# Sending data between two parse methods and getting KeyError SCRAPY

Tags: python, scrapy

I was trying to scrape this link.

> https://www.thomasnet.com/suppliers

I want to send Categories names between two parse methods but when the `scrapy crawler` follows the next page, it gives a `KeyError` for the `category_name`.

```
categories_names = response.request.meta['categories_names']
KeyError: 'categories_names'
```

How do I get the same category's name while following the next page?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    start_urls = ['https://www.thomasnet.com/suppliers']

    def parse(self, response):
        li = response.xpath('//div[@class="titled-list titled-list--covid-19-response-section titled-list--dropdown "]/ul/li/a')
        # li = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "titled-list--dropdown")]/ul/li/a')
        for each in li:
            categories_links = each.xpath('.//@href').get()
            categories = each.xpath('.//text()').get()

            yield response.follow(url=categories_links, callback=self.parse_li, meta={"categories_names": categories})


    def parse_li(self, response):
        categories_names = response.request.meta['categories_names']
        rows = response.xpath('//header[@class="profile-card__header"]/parent::div')
        for row in rows:
            links = row.xpath('.//header[@class="profile-card__header"]/h2/a/@href').get()
            company_type = row.xpath('.//span[@data-content="Company Type"]/text()[2]').get()
            yield {
                "Links": links,
                "Categories": categories_names,
                "Company Type": company_type if company_type else "N/A"
            }

        
        next_page = response.xpath('(//*[@class="icon"]/parent::a[@class="page-link"])[2]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_li)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited my answer since I misunderstood the issue before.

I believe the problem is that the `parse_li` will yield new requests recursively, but without assigning the meta params again:

```
    next_page = response.xpath('(//*[@class="icon"]/parent::a[@class="page-link"])[2]/@href').get()
    if next_page:
        yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_li)
```

As far as I can tell arbitrary data in `meta` is not propagated to following requests, so you will need to reassing it:

```
        yield response.follow(
            url=next_page,
            callback=self.parse_li,
            meta={"categories_names": categories_names}
        )
```

Consider taking a look at `cb_kwargs` in the future, they are the recommended param to pass arbitraty data between requests since Scrapy v1.7, you can check it out [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs). (*They work slightly different from meta though*)

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the meta attribute from the response object.

categories_names = response.meta['categories_names']

But, the recommended way of doing this right now would be to use cb_kwags.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions